# "[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]" always return false

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-permissions

I'm trying to validate if I have `publish_actions` permission.  Always got false.  Even when I request and get a `publish_actions` and get `succeeded=TRUE`, the re-validation still return false.

Any idea?

```
bool bGranted_publish_actions=[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"];

bool bGranted_user_photos=[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"user_photos"];

if (!bGranted_user_photos || !bGranted_publish_actions ){
    [PFFacebookUtils linkUserInBackground:[PFUser currentUser] withPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        if (succeeded) {
            bool bGranted_publish_actionsV2=[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"];
```

Comment: Getting the same here. @Franck did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Still no solution. :(

Comment: I have posted a bug report on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/713281905449321/.  May I recommend you to post a reply to confirm that you also reproduce?!  it could help :)

Comment: Solved in Parse sdk version version 1.7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved in Parse sdk version version 1.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by Franck in the comment above shows this to be a Facebook Bug. Got to wait for the next release.

Meanwhile, here's a work around.

**Workaround**

Keep a set of permissions after you call refresh on the current access token. You can keep them in the `AppDelegate` or just in the class that deals with facebook.

```
[FBSDKAccessToken refreshCurrentAccessToken:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *resultDictionary = (NSDictionary *) result;
        NSArray *permissionsArray= [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSMutableSet *permissionsSet = [NSMutableSet new];

        for (NSDictionary *permissionDic in permissionsArray) {
            if ([[permissionDic objectForKey:@"status"] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"granted"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                [permissionsSet addObject:[permissionDic objectForKey:@"permission"]];
            }
        }
        blockSelf.permissions = permissionsSet;
    }];
```

Note - `blockSelf.permissions` is a `NSSet` property on the object calling refresh.